# Using ptrace to track all execve() calls across children

Tags: c, linux, system-calls, ptrace

I am trying to write a tool on Linux CentOS to track all spawned processes and what is run.  In essence, I'm interested in walking all fork/clones and emitting all the command-lines from `execve()`.  Strace already does (some of) this, but it also truncates the calls and the arguments.  I also wanted to better understand how `ptrace()` works.

So, the first roadblock was figuring out how to use `ptrace()` to walk a fork/clone without having the tracing program require to fork a copy of itself.  I dug in and found out how strace does this.  Since fork is implemented with clone on Linux, I noticed that strace pounds some bits into the clone syscall to enable child tracing w/o any extra headache.

So, in essence the code is just a big:

```
while (1) {
    int pid = wait3(-1,...);

    /* process what happened */

    ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, pid,...);
}
```

This works fine for relatively simple processes like `/bin/sh`, however, some processes are causing the `wait()` to hang indefinitely.  The only thing I've been able to determine is that the process I'm tracing is performing a `sys_rt_sigsuspend()` on it's child (so, the tracer's grandchild) and then things wedge.

I was curious if there's a sane way I can debug what might be happening.  Something is clearly preventing the process tree from making forward progress

Here's the source code of the program in question:

```
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* For the clone flags
 */
#include <sched.h>

/* #include <errno.h> */

#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/user.h>

/* Defines our syscalls like 
 */
#include <sys/syscall.h>

#include <sys/reg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <signal.h>

#include <ctype.h>

#include <map>

using namespace std;

char bufstr[4096];

#ifdef __x86_64__
#define REG_ACC  RAX
#define REG_ARG1 RDI
#define REG_ARG2 RSI
#else
#define REG_ACC  EAX
#define REG_ARG1 EBX
#define REG_ARG2 ECX
#endif

/* Trace control structure per PID that we're tracking
 */
class tcb {
    int      pid_;
    int entering_;

    public:

    tcb(int pid, int entering = 1) : pid_(pid), entering_(entering) {};
    tcb()                          : pid_(-1)                       {};
    // tcb(const tcb& p)              : pid_(pid.pid()), entering_(entering.entering()) {};
    int&       pid() { return      pid_; }
    int&  entering() { return entering_; }
};

/* Fetch a string from process (pid) at location (ptr).  Buf is the place
 * to store the data with size limit (size).  Return the number of bytes
 * copied.
 */
int get_string(int pid, long ptr, char *buf, int size)
{
    long data;
    char *p = (char *) &data;
    int j = 0;

    while ((data = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, pid, (void *) ptr, 0)) && j < size) {
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < sizeof(data) && j < size; i++, j++) {
            if (!(buf[j] = p[i]))
                goto done;
        }
        ptr += sizeof(data);
    }

    done:

    buf[j] = '\0';

    return j;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int status = 0;
    long scno = 0;
    // int entering = 1;
    struct user_regs_struct regs;
    map<int, tcb> pidTable;
    struct sigaction sa;


    /* Setup 
     */


    int pid = fork();



    if (!pid && argc) {
        if (ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, 0, 0) < 0) {
            perror("ptrace(PTRACE_ME,... ");

            exit(1);
        }
        execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]);
    } else {
        sa.sa_flags = 0;
        sa.sa_handler = SIG_DFL;
        sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
        sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL);

        waitpid(pid, &status, 0);

        pidTable[pid] = tcb(pid);

        fprintf(stderr, "pid is %d\n", pidTable[pid].pid());

        while (!pidTable.empty()) {
            if (pid > 0) {
                //fprintf(stderr, "%d: Restarting %d\n", getpid(), pid);
                if (ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, pid, 0, 0) < 0) {
                    perror("ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL,...");
                    exit(1);
                }
            }

            // waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
            // pid = waitpid(-1, &status, 0);
            pid = wait3(&status, __WALL, 0);

            // fprintf(stderr, "Pid from wait is %d\n", pid);

            if (pid < 0) {
                perror("waitpid");
                break;
            } else {

                /* fprintf(stderr, "%d: Status is: ", pid); */

                /*
                if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "exited");
                } else if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "exited");
                } else if (WIFSTOPPED(status), "stopped") {
                    fprintf(stderr, "stopped");
                } else if (WIFCONTINUED(status)) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "continued");
                }
                fprintf(stderr, "\n");
                */

                if (WIFEXITED(status) || WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
                    /* Probably empty the table here */
                    pidTable.erase(pid);

                    fprintf(stderr, "Detect process term/kill %d\n", pid);

                    /* if (ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, pid, 0, 0) < 0) {
                        perror("ptrace");
                    } */

                    pid = -1;

                    continue;
                }
            }

            ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, 0, &regs);

#ifdef __x86_64__
            scno = regs.orig_rax;
#else
            scno = regs.orig_eax;
#endif /* __x86_64__ */

            if (scno == SYS_execve) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%d: Exec branch\n", pid);
                if (pidTable[pid].entering()) {
                    long ldata, ptr, ptr1;

                    ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, 0, &regs);

                    #ifdef __x86_64__
                    ptr = regs.rdi;
                    #else
                    ptr = regs.ebx;
                    #endif /* __x86_64__ */

                    fprintf(stderr, "%d: exec(", pid);

                    if (ptr) {
                        get_string(pid, ptr, bufstr, sizeof(bufstr));

                        fprintf(stderr, "%s", bufstr);

                    } 

                    #ifdef __x86_64__
                    ptr1 = regs.rsi;
                    #else
                    ptr1 = regs.ecx;
                    #endif /* __x86_64__ */


                    for (; ptr1; ptr1 += sizeof(unsigned long)) {
                        ptr = ptr1;
                        /* Indirect through ptr since we have char *argv[] */
                        ptr = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, pid, (void *) ptr, 0);

                        if (!ptr)
                            break;

                        get_string(pid, ptr, bufstr, sizeof(bufstr));
                        fprintf(stderr, ", %s", bufstr);
                    }
                    fprintf(stderr, ")\n");

                    pidTable[pid].entering() = 0;
                }
                else {
                    long acc = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER, pid, sizeof(unsigned long) * REG_ACC, 0);
                    pidTable[pid].entering() = 1;
                    fprintf(stderr, "%d: Leaving exec: eax is %ld\n", pid, acc);
                }
            } else if (scno == SYS_fork || scno == SYS_clone) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%d: fork/clone branch\n", pid);
                if (pidTable[pid].entering()) {
                    long flags = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER, pid, (sizeof(unsigned long) * REG_ARG1), 0);

                    fprintf(stderr, "%d: Entering fork/clone\n", pid);
                    pidTable[pid].entering() = 0;

                    if (ptrace(PTRACE_POKEUSER, pid, (sizeof(unsigned long) * REG_ARG1), flags | CLONE_PTRACE & 
                                                                                         ~(flags & CLONE_VFORK ? 
                                                                                         CLONE_VFORK | CLONE_VM : 0)) < 0) {
                        perror("ptrace");
                    }

                    if (ptrace(PTRACE_POKEUSER, pid, (sizeof(unsigned long) * REG_ARG2), 0) < 0) {
                        perror("ptrace");
                    }

                } else {
                    // int child;

                    ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, 0, &regs);

                    #ifdef __x86_64__
                    fprintf(stderr, "%d: Leaving fork/clone: rax = %ld\n", pid, regs.rax);
                    #else
                    fprintf(stderr, "%d: Leaving fork/clone: eax = %ld\n", pid, regs.eax);
                    #endif

                    pidTable[pid].entering() = 1;

                    #ifdef __x86_64__
                    if (regs.rax <= 0) {
                    #else
                    if (regs.eax <= 0) {
                    #endif
                        continue;
                    }

                    #ifdef __x86_64__
                    int newpid = regs.rax;
                    #else
                    int newpid = regs.eax;
                    #endif
                    pidTable[newpid] = tcb(newpid, 0);
                    //pidTable[newpid] = tcb(newpid, 1);
                    //pidTable[newpid] = pidTable[pid];
                    fprintf(stderr, "%d: forked child is %d\n", pid, newpid);
                }
            } else if (scno == SYS_exit) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%d: exit syscall detected\n", pid);
            } else if (scno < 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Negative syscall number for %d\n", pid);
                exit(1);
            } else {
                fprintf(stderr, "%d: Scno is %ld\n", pid, scno);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Uname -a reports 2.6.29.4 for me, but my manuals and headers all conform to the pre-PTRACE_O_... options.

Comment: So, just use modern manuals, e.g. from the internet site: http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace

Answer (score 8):

By the way. `strace -f -s99999 -e trace=clone,execve` appears to give good-quality results.
To see a trace of strace's own actions, you might try systemtap, ie.

`# stap -e 'probe syscall.ptrace {if (execname()=="strace") log(argstr)}' -c 'strace COMMAND'`

(Current systemtap doesn't pretty-print the ptrace arguments quite rightly.)

Or you can strace strace:

`strace -e trace=ptrace strace -f -s99999 -e trace=clone,execve COMMAND`

Comment: Thanks, I have used strace in this manner before with some success.  I did notice in some cases that strace has trouble navigating a mixture of 32 and 64-bit binaries.  In a prior tool I wrote relying on LD_PRELOAD I actually had to read the first few bits of the binary to determine the system type and act accordingly.

There is one other requirement that I neglected to mention.  I wanted to dump the environment for all the children so I could easily re-create the precise running conditions if I needed to rerun the program.  I can't get that with strace.

Answer (score 3):

There are flags of ptrace PTRACE_SETOPTIONS subcall: PTRACE_O_TRACEFORK, PTRACE_O_TRACEEXEC, and PTRACE_O_TRACEEXIT. More is at man page of ptrace.

Comment: These flags (PTRACE_O_TRACEFORK) are not present in all versions of Linux and thus ptrace().  Our systems don't have them.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the exact same issue, and found the solution by stracing strace.

After you get an event via `waitpid()`, you gotta call

```
ptrace(PTRACE_GETSIGINFO, pid, NULL, &sig_data)
```

and if `sig_data.si_signo` is `SIGTRAP`, you do whatever you currently do, but if not, you need to store the signal number and use it as the last argument to

```
ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, pid, 0, sig)
```

That way the signal (in my case `SIGCHLD`) is properly forwarded to the tracee.